# (Done) What part of this question is unclear?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This question [Is an experience certificate from an unregistered company valid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120983/is-an-experience-certificate-from-an-unregistered-company-valid) was closed as "unclear".

Other than a bit of language (which I cleaned up), I'm having a hard time imagining what isn't clear. It seems like an extremely straightforward question to me, and likely has a definitive answer.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Last reopen vote cast.

Answer (score 3):

Looks perfectly clear to me, I'd hazard a guess that "Unclear" here is being used with that extra special TWP meaning of "I don't understand this question because it's not from my jurisdiction, better close it quick!"

**Voted to re-open**

Comment: Thanks. You may be right about that "extra special" meaning.

Comment: Any time @JoeStrazzere

Comment: I cast the final close vote while going through the CV queue based on both the state of the question and the ambiguity around valid (i.e. valid for which purpose exactly?).

Comment: @Lilienthal - I assumed "valid" for the same purpose that all other experience letters are used.